Why does the robot_localization Dual-EKF NavSatTransform example config not use the IMU orientation yaw for the EKF nodes?
I noticed that, for the dual-ekf navsat transform example of the robot_localization package, the EKF nodes are configured to use the IMU like this:
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  false, # <-- note the false value here
              false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]

Whereas the "normal" EKF example config goes like this:
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true, # <-- note the true value here
              false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]


The order of the values is x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az.

Is there a reason why the Dual-EKF NavSat config would prefer to not use the yaw provided by the IMU? How would I choose a sensible value for my application in general?
